# Is it possible to use CuDNNLSTM with Google Colab's TPU?

Tags: google-colaboratory, tpu

I am able to do this with their **GPU**, but with their **TPU** it retrieves me an error...
Does anybody around here know what **I'm** **missing**, please?
Does it make sense to actually use the TPU with CuDNNLSTM? Or is CuDNNLSTM just tailored for GPU?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: TPU doesn't support CUDA or CuDNN.  It will require a different software stack.  I'm removing the `cuda` tag because a question about how to run something on TPU really has nothing to do with CUDA.

Answer (score 4):

[keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/keras/layers/CuDNNLSTM) is only supported on GPUs. But in Tensorflow 2 built-in LSTM and GRU layers have been updated to leverage CuDNN kernels by default when a GPU is available.

Below is the details from [Performance optimization and CuDNN kernels](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn#performance_optimization_and_cudnn_kernels):

> In TensorFlow 2.0, the built-in LSTM and GRU layers have been updated to leverage CuDNN kernels by default when a GPU is available.
> With this change, the prior keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM/CuDNNGRU layers have been deprecated, and you can build your model without worrying about the hardware it will run on.

You can just use the built-in LSTM layer: [tf.keras.layers.LSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM)  and it will work on both TPUs and GPUs.

Comment: Awesome! I wasn't aware of that in tf 2
Thanks for this input: it was useful.